# Understanding prime factor decomposition function in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time understanding part of this function. It takes an input and prints the prime decomposition of it starting with 2.

I'm confused about 2 parts:

1. Isn't the `while()` loop always satisfied in the case of 6? Doesn't 6 % 2 always equal 0?
2. I don't quite get the `if($cnt)` so if it's true or 1 then concatenate `$factors` to itself and the `strval()` but why add it to itself if it was an empty string beforehand? Can anyone explain this clearer than my poor understanding? I really wanna understand it better. Thank you.

   ```
   function primeFactors($n) {
       if ($n < 2) return "(".strval($n).")";
       $factors = "";
       for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
           $cnt = 0;
           while ($n % $i == 0) {
               $cnt++;
               $n = $n / $i;
               echo $cnt . " ";
           }
           if ($cnt) {
               $factors = $factors . "(".strval($i);
               if ($cnt > 1) {
                   $factors = $factors . "**".strval($cnt);
               }
               $factors .= ")";
           }
       }
       echo $factors;
       return $factors;
   }

   primeFactors(6); // (2)(3)
   ```

Comment: Why sling strings when this should be easier with arrays?

Comment: Well this is supposed to be returned in string format. Thanks for asking.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is it'd be easier to split this into two parts, one that just works with a well-defined data structure like an array of numbers, or an array of number+exponent pairs, and a second function can convert that into whatever format you want, roughly using the *Presenter Pattern*. This makes testing a lot easier, and generally manipulating array data is way easier than with strings.

Comment: Make an array and then use `implode()` at the end to combine them into a string.

Comment: The function "should", in an ideal situation, return an array like `primeFactors(75)` returns `[3=>1, 5=>2]` where the prime factors are keys and the powers are values. The function provides the information, then code elsewhere can be responsible for presenting that in a human-readable format.

Comment: The code is also extremely inefficient. You should look up a modern, optimised algorithm for prime factorisation (eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) and go from there. Because your code does things like check if `4` is a prime factor of your input. Or `6`. Or `9` (at least, assuming your input is bigger). For a large prime number, your function would run for a *very* long time.

Comment: @tadman: Thank you, I'll review that when I have free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The value of `$n` changes each time through the loop. Since `6 % 2 == 0` is true, it executes the statement `$n = $n / $i;`. This sets `$n` to `3`, so the next time it tests `3 % 2 == 0`. This time the test fails, so the loop stops.
2. Any non-zero value is true, so the `if ($count)` block is executed whenever `$i` is a factor of `$n`.

> Why add it to itself if it was an empty string beforehand?

`$factors` is only an empty string when the function first starts. After it finds the first factor, it contains that factor. And each time it finds another factor, it adds the new factor to the end of this string.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, although I appreciate the comments above as well. Thank you sir! Will accept shortly.

Comment: One question I had is one the second iteration in the example using 6, what is the point of `$n = $n / $i`? In that case it's **3 / 3** but we don't seem to use `$n` anymore after that ..

Comment: The idea is to keep dividing by `$i` to find out how many times the factor is used. For instance, `8 == 2 * 2 * 2` so it will show `(2)**3`

Comment: For 12 the result will be `(2)**2(3)`

Comment: The number after `**` is `$count` when it's not 1.

Comment: Last thing: What do you mean in your answer **"so the next time it tests 3 % 2 == 0."** wouldn't it be **3 % 3 == 0** and run through one more time? Since `i` would be incremented to 3 the second time the for loop runs ... unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Why would it test `3 % 3`? We reassigned `$n`, but `$i` hasn't changed. `$i` doesn't change until the next iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: The `for` loop doesn't go to the next iteration until the `while` loop stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223378/discussion-between-rec0nstr-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but many are looking for this algorithm

```
public static function primeFactors($what)
{
    if (!is_int($what)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23] as $s) {
        if ($what % $s === 0) {
            return $s;
        }
    }
    $g = 0;
    $it = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3 || $it < 1000; $i++) {
        $t = ((rand(0, 127) & 15) + 17) % $what;
        $x = (rand() % ($what - 1)) + 1;
        $y = $x;
        $lim = 1 << ($i + 18);
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $lim; $j++) {
            $it++;
            $a = $x;
            $b = $x;
            $c = $t;
            while ($b) {
                if ($b & 1) {
                    $c += $a;
                    if ($c >= $what) {
                        $c -= $what;
                    }
                }
                $a += $a;
                if ($a >= $what) {
                    $a -= $what;
                }
                $b >>= 1;
            }
            $x = $c;
            $z = ($x < $y) ? $what + $x - $y : $x - $y;
            $g = self::gcd($z, $what);
            if ($g != 1) {
                break;
            }

            if (!($j & ($j - 1))) {
                $y = $x;
            }
        }
        if ($g > 1 && $g < $what) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($g > 1 && $g < $what) {
        return $g;
    }

    return $what;
}

private function gcd($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return $a;
    }
    while ($b > 0) {
        $a2 = $a;
        $a = $b;
        $b = bcmod($a2, $b);
    }

    return $a;
}
```